# Issue with interactive shell with popen

Tags: python

I am trying to run shell command from python in interactive mode. But somehow the output is not working well. For example, if I write ls two times, the first time, it shows just a single file and the 2nd time shows all the files.

```
import subprocess
import select

# Start the interactive shell process
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)

# Loop to interact with the shell
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a command (or 'exit' to quit): ")

    if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
        cmd.stdin.write('exit\n')
        cmd.stdin.flush()
        break

    # Send the user input to the shell process
    cmd.stdin.write(user_input + '\n')
    cmd.stdin.flush()

    # Read and display the shell output
    output_lines = []
    breakpoint()
    while True:
        # Use select to check if data is available to read
        ready_to_read, _, _ = select.select([cmd.stdout], [], [], 0.1)
        if not ready_to_read:
            break

        line = cmd.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        output_lines.append(line.strip())

    print('\n'.join(output_lines))

# Close the shell process
cmd.communicate()
```

Comment: Do you write all of this into an interactive shell ? Why not just using a file ?

Comment: This is a toy example python script.